# Running Asp.Net Mvc Application Under Php Site (WordPress) on IIS

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc, iis

I've added Asp.Net Mvc Web application as Application to Php Web Site. (/asp folder)

when I call to x.com/asp Asp.Net Web Application must be executed.
But I'm getting this error:

```
HTTP Error 403.18 - Forbidden
The specified request cannot be processed in the application pool that is configured for this      resource on the Web server.
Detailed Error Information
Module  IIS Web Core
Notification    BeginRequest
Handler php-5.6.2
Error Code  0x00000000
Requested URL   http://www.x.com:80/index.php
Physical Path   D:\WebSites\x.com\index.php
Logon Method    Not yet determined
Logon User  Not yet determined
```

I've added these to web.config:

```
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
<handlers>
        <remove name="PHP_via_FastCGI" />
<remove name="php-5.6.2" />
   <remove name="PHP53_via_FastCGI" />
<remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />

  <add name="OzImageHandler" verb="GET" path="/gorsel/*" type="Oz.Services.ImageHandler, Oz.Services" />
  <!--<add name="LoggerHandler" verb="*" path="*.logger" type="JSNLog.LoggerHandler, JSNLog" resourceType="Unspecified" />-->

  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">

  <remove name="RoleManager" />
  <remove name="Session" />
  <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule" />
</modules>
```

But still php application handles /asp requests?

What is the solution?

IIS 7.5 Windows Server 2008 R2

Php application is WordPress

Comment: did you ever resolve this as I have a similar problem where my site is breaking when adding it as a sub to wordpress

Comment: No, I used them as seperate applications.

Answer (score 0):

Getting an ASP.NET MVC application working under WordPress is possible by editing the web.config and then after setting it to read-only so that no changes will be applied by WordPress afterwards.

```
<rule name="asp.netwebsite" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="false">
            <match url=".*/virtualdirectory.*" />
            <action type="None" />
                <conditions>
                </conditions>
        </rule>
        <rule name="wordpress" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^store.*" negate="true" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^virtualdirectory.*" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="Index.php" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
```

I hope that this can help someone in the future.
Also it is very important to use Razor commands like `@Url.Content()` to ensure that the references are handled properly.